# Counting Objects via Mean-Shift Segmentation

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to use mean-shift segmentation to count the objects found in an image. I've been working with `[pyrMeanShiftFiltering][1]` in OpenCV. Using the following code, I'm able to produce an image that has been segmented. However, I do not know how to actually *count* the number of "items" in that image.

Simply running `pyrMeanShiftFiltering( img, res, spatialRad, colorRad, maxPyrLevel );` on this image
[image: unsegmented books]

produces *this* image
[image]

In this example, it doesn't seem much different, although there are some images where the segmentation makes a huge difference in the colors and such present. However, for the majority of test cases, I'm going to assume that the colors will **not** be terribly distinct and that the edges will **not** be distinct (as they are in the example given) enough to use edge detection on the image itself.

Based off of this, how can I go about finding the number of objects found inside of that image? I'm looking for a bit of code, although any poke in the correct direction will help.

Answer (score 2):

If the objects contain different colors (and those colors are distinctive) the simplest soultion would be to count how many clusters are there (remove cluster for the white color since the pages are white/yellow).

On images that you have shown you could also use corner detector since you have very distinctive corners, then look the surrounding and filter those corners by color (the surrounding  color has to contain some color and white one (from pages)) then match corners that lie in the same vertical line and finally count them.

One other idea is to extrapolate white/yellow color from pages (clustering + histogram filtering) and to count different blobs.

Maybe the best approach is to extrapolate white/yeelow color from pages by finding cover color (blue, green) and closest white color => find blobs. Those blobs can be labeled to the closest cover color. Then you have blobs that present pages and are labeled according the closest cover color.
Those blobs may be broken to several pieces (one book partly covers the other book) and two different blobs may belong to the same object (a book with multiple color cover)
but you now that those blobs have to be rectangular.  So you could find lines in that binarized image and try to connect them with closest line. Then you will finally have one blob that matches one book. Finally you can count them.

Comment: I've added a bit more information about the typical images I'll be using. However, I would like to try a few different things. If you could provide a little bit of code, which would work with OpenCV, in the direction of using the cluster's color or counting different blobs, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The background is always white ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it should always be distinctive from the objects I'll be trying to identify.

Comment: Well for prototyping I use EmguCV +  AForge .NET (has functions to count blobs) + Accrod .NET (machine learning). The documentation of these libraries is great, so you could search it on the internet how to count blobs using AForge .NET or simmilar. I did not see functions to wrok with blobs in OpenCV (I think you need to download an extension?)

Comment: The best way is to use MATLAB.